# how to append string value in for loop to data frame

Tags: python, jupyter

I am converting some data written in Hex to binary number.
I am using for loop to go over every single data and convert it into binary number.
While operating for loop I was hoping to store those data in to dataframe but some how the result shows only one value.

[image]

Please help me out how to store iterated value into dataframe. Thanks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you keep overwriting the DataFrame `df` in the last loop with a new DataFrame. It would be better if you first create a DataFrame and then expand it for each line:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['string_values'])
for i in range(0, len(index_a)):
    a = str(i)
    df.loc[i] = {'string_values': a}
```

This may not be very efficient, but you end up with a DataFrame with all values as rows.